# expose apache server to local wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, apache-http-server

I have two computer

Computer A connect to internet by wifi. (IP: 192.168.0.101)

Computer B connect to computer A with direct LAN cable. (C.A IP: 192.168.137.1, C.B IP: 192.168.137.2)

Computer A sharing internet connection with computer B.

Now, my problem is, computer B is running a web server (apache). How I setup computer B to expose web server to another device in wifi network (IP: 192.168.0.xxx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into the Internet Connection Sharing options (under the Sharing tab in the network adapter properties), click Settings, and click Web Server (HTTP).  Put computer B's IP address in the field where asked.  This should expose Computer B's services to your LAN, and should allow you to access port 80 of computer B, when contacting port 80 of computer A -- based on my understanding.

I haven't personally used this feature but it looks very similar to port forwarding settings in routers.  Internet Connection Sharing essentially sets your computer up to be a NAT router.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But a little confuse here. The ethernet adapter or wifi adapter? And on computer A or B? Computer A running windows 7 and computer B (which host web server) running Mac OS X ML.

Comment: The wifi is what you're sharing, so go into the properties for the wifi adapter, go to the Settings button, and check Web Server.  Then in the Service Settings you'd need to put the IP of computer B, 192.168.137.2 as you've listed above.